# Base Input hides text instead of showing it inside the field

Tags: vue.js, input, placeholder

I have downloaded [this design kit](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/vue-argon-dashboard) for Vue.js.

The thing is that when I'm writing text in it, it views the text I wrote, but after I focus out from the field, the text is hidden and the placeholder is shown back, but I couldn't understand why it does that.

When I'm printing the value of the field after writing in it, I get the value that I wrote, but I simply cannot see it inside the field.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<base-input class="input-group-alternative mb-3"
    :placeholder="email"
    addon-right-icon="ni ni-email-83"
    v-model="emailVal"
    required="true"
    :dir="dir">
</base-input>
```

I'm passing the `email` parameter as "Email Address" and the `dir` parameter as "ltr".

Could you please help me understand why it doesn't keeps my input inside the field?

Comment: so do you mean `placeholder` is not one of the props of `base-input` and you change the `base-input` code to accept `placeholder` ? If that is the case may be you also need to show us how you change the `base-input` code, because maybe there is some conflict after you add that props

Comment: @JakeLam My bad, apparently it has nothing to do with the placeholder, as I just tried to remove the placeholder prop and the text is still hidden. Edited the question as well

Comment: did you declare `emailVal` in your data object

Comment: @JakeLam Nope, apparently that solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that I didn't declared `emailVal` in my data object.

I added it like this, and it worked:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            email: 'Email Address',
            dir: 'ltr',
            emailVal: ''
        }
    }
}
```